# iOS/mobile detection with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, devise, browser-detection

So I'm using User Agent detection to serve different views within my app by serving `example.mobile.haml` rather than `example.html.haml`. It's all working fine apart from some funny things happening with devise views.

When I hit the root as a desktop UA (Safari, Mac OS) it correctly redirects to /login with a flash, when I do this as a mobile UA it doesn't redirect and displays only the flash and renders no additional HTML.

Similarly, hitting /logout as a desktop UA correctly logs out and redirects to /login as it should. But doing this as a mobile UA hits /logout, destroys your session but doesn't redirect.

I've followed all the instructions on the devise wiki but this is all that won't work. The code that does all of the detection is below:

```
#application_controller.rb

def format_for_mobile
  request.format = :mobile if mobile_user_agent?
end

def mobile_user_agent?
    request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
    request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][MOBILE_USER_AGENTS]
end


# config/initializers/devise.rb

config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :to_mobile]


# config/initializers/mobile_responder.rb

ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
  alias :to_mobile :to_html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out myself. The `before_filter :format_for_mobile` was before authenticate user, that fixed the /login issue.

For /logout, I had to do the following:

```
# controllers/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_filter :format_for_mobile, :except => :destroy
end
```